# There are about 70 million inserts in a week.What indexes should i use on my columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-indexes

I have got a table in sql server 2012 which gets almost 66 million inserts in a week. On which columns should I use indexes?

```
create TABLE [dbo].[Details](
        [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [WorkflowContentMetricsID] [bigint] not null,
        [ContentType] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
        [SourceID] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [DestinationID] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [ParentSourceID] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Status] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Debug] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Metadata] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [StatusCategory] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [SangamWorkflowRunID] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
        [StartDateTime] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkflowContentDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

The query which I use is

```
SELECT ID
      ,WorkflowContentMetricsID
      ,ContentType
      ,SourceID
      ,DestinationID
      ,ParentSourceID
      ,Title
      ,[Status]
      ,Debug
      ,Metadata
      ,StatusCategory
FROM WorkflowContentDetails
WHERE ContentType NOT IN ('Image' , 'EntityList')
AND SangamWorkflowRunID = @SangamWorkflowRunID
And StatusCategory in (@StatusCategory)
```

Comment: That depends on what queries you intend to run, not how many inserts there are.

Comment: This insertion is a daily process or weekly ?

Comment: it is a daily process

Comment: @Ben if I use covering indexes then that will take a lot of time, if I am not wrong

Comment: @ben is correct. Since your table doesn't include constraints other than the primary key, there is no need for indexes to support the insert operation. To decide what indexes are needed to support queries, you would have to know what queries you will run / how often. Inserts and queries are unrelated in this regard.

Comment: That averages 100 inserts per second, which is a lot. If you have too many indexes that will slow it down, true. What queries do you need to run? That's vital information. If you don't run any queries ever, you need zero indexes. ***So: what queries?***

Comment: SELECT ID
      ,WorkflowContentMetricsID
      ,ContentType
      ,SourceID
      ,DestinationID
      ,ParentSourceID
      ,Title
      ,[Status]
      ,Debug
      ,Metadata
      ,StatusCategory
FROM WorkflowContentDetails
WHERE ContentType NOT IN ('Image' , 'EntityList')
AND SangamWorkflowRunID = @SangamWorkflowRunID
And StatusCategory in (@StatusCategory)

Comment: `WorkflowContentDetails`  is different table, You had provided schema for `Details` table.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only for insert (as  your question states), then do not use **indexes** on any column. The more the indexes a table has, slower the execution becomes.

The `insert` statement is the only operation that cannot directly benefit from **indexing** because it has no `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes do not help with inserting - they hurt because they must be written to as well. If you only ever query the table with the one query provided, create an index just for that query. It should include selective columns. `SangamWorkflowRunID`, `StatusCategory` and `ContentType` appear to be useful here.

More cannot be said with the information provided. I suggest you invest a little time in understanding how indexing works and how it influences both `SELECT` and DML performance.

For the inserts themselves use a form of the bulk insert facilities SQL Server provides. 66m rows will not take particularly long to insert.